# Use an enum or abstract base class in a game in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, enums, abstract-class

**Context**: 
    In a game, when each level is completed, a Rating is stored based on player performance: *Poor, Good, Excellent*.
    The ratings are later used to evaluate the game play as a whole.

**Question**:
    Should the Rating object contain a rating choice as an enum {RatingPoor, RatingGood, RatingExcellent} or should I make an abstract base class Rating with subclasses RatingPoor, RatingGood, RatingExcellent.

**Other details**
Ratings don't have complex behaviors, they are just generated from play stats at a very low frequency like every minute. They're assigned to a collection and averaged at the end of a game to generate a Rank *(like Cadet, Pilot, Captain, Admiral)*. At the end of a level, the rating is shown as an icon *(think stars, like in Angry Birds)*. They also get stored when the player pauses or suspends the game.

I would also appreciate knowing *how to decide* on enum vs. subclass, given this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This situation is basic enough that you should just use an `enum`. I typically use `enum`'s when something can be represented by an integer (a mode, a setting, or in your case, a rating,). A subclass is only necessary if your ratings would include additional attributes or relationships.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a subclass would be overkill for this situation, as it doesn't sound like you're attaching any particular methods to each rating.  I would use an enum.

I'm no expert in software design, but I generally err towards using the simplest data structures that will get a job done-- in general, if the problem doesn't require you to have methods travelling with the data, a class would be more heavyweight than necessary.